Compute: $\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}} \frac{\sqrt{\sec(2x)}}{\cos(x)+\sqrt{\cos(2x)}}dx$
I found my first integration bee journal where I wrote a bunch of integral problems during high school. Unfortunately, I only wrote answers but not the entire solutions. A lot of these problems are very low quality and god awful, and now that I've found this book, I'm going through them. This integral is one of them:
$$\int_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}^{\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sqrt{\sec(2x)}}{\cos(x)+\sqrt{\cos(2x)}}dx$$
Turning all of them in terms of cosines looks very nasty, and I don't know if I wanna multiply top and bottom with $\sin(x)$ just to perform $u=\cos(x)$. Is there a nicer and quicker way to solve this integral?

Hint: it may help to note that your integrand can be written as $$\frac{\csc(x)\cot(x)}{\sqrt{\cos(2x)}}-\csc^2(x),$$ i.e. your integrand has a simple antiderivative.

0.0 How??? I'm trying to find a way to get to that convenient form.

@Silver rationalise the denominator :)

@KStar OHHHHHHHHH!!! YOOOOOO, I didn't realize you could conjugate the denominator like that!!! Thank you so much!!!
Holy hell that's such a sneaky move...

Apply $\cos 2x=\cos^2x-\sin^2x$
\begin{aligned}
&\int_ {-\frac\pi4} ^\frac{\pi}{4}  \frac{\sqrt{\sec2x}}{\cos(x)+\sqrt{\cos2x}}dx\\
=&\int_{0} ^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{2\sec^2 x}{\sqrt{1-\tan^2x}\ (1+\sqrt{1-\tan^2x})}dx\overset{ \tan x= \text{sech}\ t}=\int _ {0} ^\infty 2e^{-t}dt=2\\
\end{aligned}

that sech(x) substitution was surprisingly clean 0.0

$$\int \frac{\cot(x)\csc(x)}{\sqrt{\cos(2x)}}dx-\int \csc^2(x)dx$$
Solving:
$$\int \frac{\cot(x)\csc(x)}{\sqrt{\cos(2x)}}dx$$
Prepare for substitution,
use:
$$\cos(2x)=\cos^2(x)-\sin^2(x)\\
\sin(x)=\frac{1}{\csc(x)}\\
\cos(x)=\frac{\cot(x)}{\csc(x)}\\
\csc^2(x)=\cot^2(x)+1\\
\int -\left(-\frac{\cot(x)}{\sqrt{\cot^2(x)-1}}\right)\csc^2(x)dx$$
Substitute
$$u=\cot(x) \to du=-\csc^2(x)dx\\=-\int \frac{u}{u^2-1}du$$
by substituting $$v=u^2-1 \to dv=2udu=-\sqrt{\cot^2(x)-1}$$
Now solve
$$\int \csc^2(x)dx=-\cot(x)$$
The solution
$$=\cot(x)-\sqrt{\cot^2(x)-1}+c$$
Definite integral
$=2$

You have deleted another answer and rewrote it as a new one. It can help to edit the deleted answer and then undelete it instead.

I would advise you to show how to get from the original form of the integrand to the first line in your current answer.

\begin{align}I&=\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{-\frac{\pi}{4}}\frac{\sqrt{\sec(2x)}}{\cos(x)+\sqrt{\cos(2x)}}dx\\
&=2\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{0}\frac{\sqrt{\sec(2x)}}{\cos(x)+\sqrt{\cos(2x)}}dx\\
&=2\int^{\frac{\pi}{4}}_{0}\frac{1}{\cos(2x)\left({1+\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2\cos(2x)}}}\right)}dx\end{align}
Let $y=2x$
$$I=\int^{\frac{\pi}{2}}_{0}\frac{1}{\cos(y)\left({1+\sqrt{\frac{1+\cos(y)}{2\cos(y)}}}\right)}dy$$
Let   $t^2=\frac{1+\cos(y)}{2\cos(y)}$
$$I=2\int^{\infty}_{1}\frac{dt}{(1+t)\sqrt{t^2-1}}\overset{x=1/t}{=}\int^{1}_{0}\frac{dx}{(1+x)\sqrt{1-x^2}}$$
Let $x=\sin(\theta)$
$$I=2\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{1}{1+\sin(\theta)}d\theta =2$$

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =2\int_ 0 ^\frac{\pi}{4}  \frac{\sqrt{\sec (2 x)}}{\cos x+\sqrt{\cos (2 x)}} d x \\
& =2\int_{0} ^\frac{\pi}{4} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\cos (2x)}(\cos x+\sqrt{\cos (2 x)})} d x \\
& =2\int _ {0} ^\frac{\pi}{4}\frac{\csc^2 x}{\sqrt{\csc ^2 x-2} \sqrt{\cot x+\sqrt{\csc ^2 x-2}}} d x \\
& =2\int _{1}^\infty\frac{d c}{\sqrt{c^2-1} \sqrt{c+\sqrt{c^2-1}}},\quad \textrm{ where }c=\cot x\\ \\& =2 \int _{1}^\infty\frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2-1}\left(1+\frac{c}{\sqrt{c^2-1}}\right)} d\left(\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c^2-1}}\right) \\
&=2 \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt{c^2-1}+c} d\left(\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c^2-1}}\right) \\
&=2\left[-\frac{1}{\sqrt{c+\sqrt{c^2}-1}}\right]_1^{\infty}\\&=2
\end{aligned}
$$
